# Finding the third largest element of an array by sorting it through TreeSet in a decreasing order

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator, testcase, treeset

I am trying to find the third largest element of an array by sorting it through treeset in a decreasing order, but some of the test cases fail for certain input values and most of it pass for certain input values.

*My code:*

```
// { Driver Code Starts
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class ThirdLargestElement
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while(t>0)
        {
            long n =sc.nextLong();
            Long arr[] = new Long[(int)n];
            for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
                arr[(int)i] = sc.nextLong();
            GfG g = new GfG();
            System.out.println(g.thirdLargest(arr));
        t--;
        }
    }
}// } Driver Code Ends
class GfG
{
    long thirdLargest(Long a[])
    {
    // Your code here
        if(a.length<3)
            return -1;
        else{
            TreeSet<Long> ts=new TreeSet<Long>(new myComparator());
            for(long i:a)
                ts.add(i);
            ArrayList<Long> al=new ArrayList<Long>(ts);
            return al.get(2);
        }
    }
}
class myComparator implements Comparator{
    public int compare(Object obj1,Object obj2){
        Long a=(Long) obj1;
        Long b=(Long) obj2;
        if(a<b)
            return 1;
        else if(a>b)
            return -1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }
}
```

The testcase it failed: 
[image]

[Link to the question where you can run the code](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/third-largest-element/1)

Please explain why this code failed to pass the given test case.

Comment: Simply add the numbers directly to the `TreeSet` as you obtain them from `Scanner`. Then use method [`descendingIterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#descendingIterator--)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This one**

```java
class GfG {
    long thirdLargest(Long a[]) {
        Arrays.sort(a);
        List<Long> numbers = Arrays.asList(a);
        Collections.reverse(numbers);
        return numbers.size() >= 3 ? numbers.get(2) : -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: while doing this `for(long i:a)  ts.add(i);`  Tress set remove the duplicate element. We can not insert duplicate value in `Set` or it's implemented classes. That's why your test case fail

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add elements to `TreeSet` and get third largest number using stream,

```
while(t>0)
{
    long n =sc.nextLong();
    TreeSet<Long> ts=new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingLong(Long::longValue).reversed());
    for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
        ts.add(sc.nextLong());
    long thirdLast = ts.stream()
            .limit(3)
            .skip(2)
            .mapToLong(e->e)
            .findAny().orElse(0l);

    System.out.println(thirdLast);
    t--;
}
```

Comment: but can you please tell me why my test case didnt pass as shown in the given pic?  To me, I dont see a flaw in my code.

Comment: In your code Treeset remove the duplicate value thats why your test case fail and the sequence differ while getting the element. In my first try i got the same,

Answer (score 0):

The [question](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/third-largest-element/1) states:

> the function thirdLargest ... takes two argument. The first argument is the array a[] and the second argument is the size of the array (n).

Although the question states that the array is...

> an array of distinct elements

the test cases indicate that we are dealing with an array of integers.

Personally, I don't see the need for the second method parameter, because in java an array is an object and has a `length` member. So my implementation below only takes one parameter, namely an array of `int`. Maybe the people at *geeksforgeeks.org* simply converted a question that was originally for the C language to java, since, in C, it is difficult to determine the size of any array.

Each element in a `TreeSet` must be an object, so we need to convert the elements in the `int` array to `Integer` objects. [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) will do this automatically, nonetheless my code below contains an explicit conversion. So in the method I create a `TreeSet`. Since class `Integer` implements interface [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), the default `TreeSet` constructor is sufficient. I add all the elements of the `int` array to the `TreeSet`, then obtain a descending iterator and then iterate to the third element returned by the iterator, which is the value that the method needs to return.

```java
    int thirdLargest(int[] arr) {
        int third = -1;
        if (arr != null  &&  arr.length > 2) {
            TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            for (int elem : arr) {
                set.add(Integer.valueOf(elem));
            }
            Iterator<Integer> iter = set.descendingIterator();
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                iter.next();
                if (iter.hasNext()) {
                    iter.next();
                    if (iter.hasNext()) {
                        third = iter.next().intValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return third;
    }
```

Of-course, if you want to ignore the conditions imposed by the original question, you could get the third largest element using the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```java
IntStream.of(2, 4, 1, 3, 5)
         .boxed()
         .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
         .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(2)
```